# Do I have full administrator access in my win10s C drive?

Tags: python, windows-10, administrator, chatterbot

even when I run CMD as administrator, I think I don't have full privilege. I tried running `net user username` command, and here's the result:

```
User name                    ali
Full Name
Comment
User's comment
Country/region code          000 (System Default)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            2022-11-21 12:48:19 AM
Password expires             Never
Password changeable          2022-11-21 12:48:19 AM
Password required            No
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All
Logon script
User profile
Home directory
Last logon                   2023-03-06 09:34:35 AM

Logon hours allowed          All

Local Group Memberships      *Administrators
Global Group memberships     *None
The command completed successfully.
```

but when I try to install something like chatterbot, it says I don't have admin access: `python setup.py install`

```
    C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\ChatterBot>python setup.py install
C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:516: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
  warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
running install
C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-3476.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: A) no need to install python packages as admin. B) Are you using an admin command instance?

Comment: Managing Windows is not exactly on-topic on SO...  If you decide to aks on https://superuser.com/ (which is probably more appropriate) clarify if indeed you are talking about "S" version where you know that you can't install non-store apps (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/switching-out-of-s-mode-in-windows-4f56d9be-99ec-6983-119f-031bfb28a307)